# What is this function doing?

Tags: ida, binary-analysis

I have this function, named `__ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE6__initEPKcm`.

And this is the relevant assembly:

```
mov     rdi, [rbp+var_A80]
mov     rsi, [rbp+var_A88] 
mov     rdx, [rbp+string_length]
call    __ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE6__initEPKcm
```

From what I've noticed by looking at the registers before and after calling the function, the address of RSI is incremented by string_length, but I still have no idea what RDI is doing.

Another weird thing is that the string length reported by the register is 0x046, but the address is incremented by 0x040.

The RDI is `00007FFEEFBFF240` before the call, `0000000100400040` after it.

EDIT:

IDA is not letting me debug the function, as it throws SIGBUS.

I am slowly reversing the function, i'll update here with progress.

RDI is compared with 0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0h (Why?)

Comment: This is most likely just a `std::string` constructor. From personal experience with STL code, take educated guesses and move on. You'll turn crazy if you reverse all of it. I usually just check xrefs to some function and if it looks like it may be simply creating an `std::string` from a C string, I treat the function as such until further context shows it doesn't.

Comment: One more tip to make code more readable: Go to `Options -> Demangled names -> Select names` so you don't have to look at 500 character mangled names all day.

Comment: it is a gcc demangled name _std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__init(char const*, unsigned long) as suggested turn on demangling in options and iirc ida should probably show it as standard function using flirt